# Accessing editable GridViewRow outside of RowEditing event handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my `gridview`, once a row is in `RowEditing` I would like to access a `DropDownList` in an event handler outside of `OnRowEditing`.

My gridview has these two `TemplateField`. Both have `EditItemTemplate` with a dropdownlist:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Director">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label_Director" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Director").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Director" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_Director_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" DataTextField="Category" DataValueField="Category" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="manager">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label_manager" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("manager").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_manager" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" DataTextField="Category" DataValueField="Category" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When I edit a row, `DDL_Director` is populated. This works as expected:

```
protected void gridview_emps_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    string connString = GetConnString();

    gridview_emps.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

    BindData();

    GridViewRow editingRow = gridview_emps.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];

    DropDownList DDL_Director = (editingRow.FindControl("DDL_Director") as DropDownList);
    DDL_Director.DataSource = GetCategories(connString, "Director");
    DDL_Director.DataBind();
}
```

Here's the issue: I need to populate dropdownlist DDL_manager once a value in `DDL_Director` has been selected. I attached `DDL_Director_SelectedIndexChanged` to `DDL_Director`. The debugger breaks inside `DDL_Director_SelectedIndexChanged` so I know the code is being executed:

```
protected void DDL_Director_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // Access dropdownlist control in RowEditing from here?
    
    //DropDownList DDL_manager = (editingRow.FindControl("DDL_manager") as DropDownList);
    //DDL_manager.DataSource = GetCategories(connString, "manager");
    //DDL_manager.DataBind();

}
```

The problem is that I can't populate `DDL_manager` from `DDL_Director_SelectedIndexChanged` since I don't have access to `EditingRow`.

Question: how can I populate `DDL_Manager` after selecting a value in `DDL_Director`?

Answer (score 0):

I edited `DDL_Director_SelectedIndexChanged` so it looks like below:

```
    protected void DDL_Director_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connString = GetConnString();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView_Emps.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == DataControlRowState.Edit)
            {
                DropDownList DDL_Manager = (row.FindControl("DDL_Manager") as DropDownList);
                DDL_Manager.DataSource = GetCategories(connString, "manager");
                DDL_Manager.DataBind();

            }
        }
    }
```